# How do I get the name of the active brush texture with Python?

Tags: python, scripting

How to get `active_texture.name` via python? Or get `active_texture[ID]`?

(I mean a texture in active slot)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can reference it from the brush it is applied to:

```
bpy.data.brushes['NameOfBrush'].texture
```

Or use the active brush (if the context is sculpt mode, texture mode, etc.):

```
bpy.context.brush.texture
```

Or:

```
bpy.context.sculpt.brush.texture
```

https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_api_reference.html#indirect-data-access

Comment: The 2.66 version you use in your link is old - we now have a link that always points to the newest API [www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/)

Comment: Fixed, thanks. I didn't know about the /blender_python_api_current/ trick! I normally just type 2.77 when I google something in the api b/c the search bar in the docs works horribly (you have to almost know the answer to what you are looking for to be able to find it).